# HackerRank - Climbing the Leaderboard: I don't understand why my code is exceeding the time limit

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, binary-search

[Climbing the Leaderboard](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem)

> An arcade game player wants to climb to the top of the leaderboard and
> track their ranking. The game uses Dense Ranking, so its leaderboard
> works like this:
>
> The player with the highest score is ranked number \$1\$ on the
> leaderboard. Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking
> number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following
> ranking number.
>
> #### Example
>
> \$ranked = [100, 90, 90, 80]\$
>
> \$player = [70, 80, 105]\$
>
> The ranked players will have ranks 1, 2, 2, and 3, respectively. If the
> player's scores are 70, 80 and 105, their rankings after each game are 4<sup>th</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> and
> 1<sup>st</sup>. Return `[4, 3, 1]`.
>
> #### Function Description
>
> Complete the climbingLeaderboard function in the editor below.
>
> climbingLeaderboard has the following parameter(s):
>
> - `int ranked[n]`: the leaderboard scores
> - `int player[m]`: the player's scores
>
> #### Returns
>
> - `int[m]`: the player's rank after each new score
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer \$n\$, the number of players on the
> leaderboard. The next line contains  space-separated integers \$ranked[i]\$, the
> leaderboard scores in decreasing order. The next line contains an
> integer, \$m\$, the number games the player plays. The last line contains
> space-separated integers \$player[i]\$, the game scores.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - \$1 <= n <= 2 x 10^5\$
> - \$1 <= m <= 2 x 10^5\$
> - \$0 <= ranked[i] <= 10^9\$ for \$0 <= i < n\$
> - The existing leaderboard, \$ranked\$, is in descending order.
> - The player's scores, \$scores\$, are in ascending order.
>
> #### Subtask
>
> For \$60%\$ of the maximum score:
>
> - \$1 <= n <= 200\$
> - \$1 <= m <= 200\$
>
> #### Sample Input 1
>
> ```
> 7 
> 100 100 50 40 40 20 10 
> 4 
> 5 25 50 120
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output 1
>
> 6 4 2 1

I keep getting timed out. I think my general logic is right but how can my code be optimized more?

I know there are solutions using the bisect module but I've seen very simple ones without using that. From what I can think of, maybe using while loops will speed things up?

```
def climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player):
    ranked=[i for n, i in enumerate(ranked) if i not in ranked[:n]] #remove duplicates
    
    player_rank=[]

    ranking=len(ranked)+1
    start=1
    for pi,ps in enumerate(player[::-1]):
        for ri,r in enumerate(ranked,start=start):
            if ps>=r:
                player_rank.append(ri)
                break
            else:
                ranked=ranked[1:]
                start+=1
        else:
            player_rank.append(ranking)
           
    return player_rank[::-1]
```

Comment: Are you sure the code works at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removing duplicates efficiently**

```
ranked=[i for n, i in enumerate(ranked) if i not in ranked[:n]]
```

This line creates a copy of `ranked` at each iteration, which makes it inefficient.
Since `ranked` is already sorted, create a new list and add elements one by one if different from the previous.

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary that is ordered from Python 3.7.

```
ranked = list(dict.fromkeys(ranked))
```

**Rank assignment**

The second part of the algorithm creates many copies of `ranked` in `ranked=ranked[1:]`, which might be the issue. As you said, using a while loop can speed things up. Refactored code:

```
def climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player):
    ranked = list(dict.fromkeys(ranked))
    player_rank = []
    ranking = len(ranked) + 1
    start = 0
    for pi, ps in enumerate(player[::-1]):
        j = start
        while j < len(ranked):
            if ps >= ranked[j]:
                player_rank.append(j + 1)
                break
            start += 1
            j += 1
        if j == len(ranked):
            player_rank.append(ranking)
    return player_rank[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I think ranked=ranked[1:] was the problem. I'm a bit new to code optimization, can you explain more about how that creates many copies of ranked?

Comment: @MysteriousShadow I am glad I could help. `ranked=ranked[1:]` creates many copies because it's in the for-loop.